# Debugging kernel using kgdb/gdb on arm target?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, gdb, remote-debugging, kgdb

I got `vmlinux.uimg` and `vmlinux` from my friend. The `vmlinux` is build with Linux version 4.14.10. I have two machines:

- target (arm 32 bit architecture) and
- host (x86 architecture)

Both systems are connected with wire, port numbers are `/dev/ttySAC3` and `/dev/ttyUSB0` respectively. Target boot up by reading image file `vmlinux.uimg` from sd card. I want to debug this `vmlinux` from my host machine.

The steps I am following are:

1. Start minicom in host.
2. Type

   ```
   echo ttySAC3,115200 > /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc in minicom.
   ```

   I am getting "KGDB: Registered I/O driver kgdboc".
3. Type

   ```
   echo g >/proc/sysrq-trigger in minicom
   ```

   I am getting "sysrq DEBUG and Entering KGDB".
4. Close minicom.
5. Go to vmlinux folder through terminal in host machine.
6. Type

   ```
   gdb vmlinux
   ```

   [Note: this gdb I am using is 7.10 version for arm]
7. In GDB type

   ```
   target remote /dev/ttyUSB0
   ```

   It give me a message

   ```
   Remote debugging using /dev/ttyUSB0 0xc0d14f5 in sysrq_dbg_op()
   ```
8. In GDB type

   ```
   b do_mmap_pgoff
   ```

   I am getting a message

   ```
   breakpoint 1 at xxxx: do_map_pgoff (4 location)
   ```
9. In GDB type

   ```
   cont
   ```

   This gives me a message

   ```
   Continuing.
   ```

   and then does nothing..

The problems:

1. GDB `continue` is not working as expected. I am expecting last step(9) to continue with target restart and hit the break point instead it is getting crash.
2. GDB `step` and `next` are not working as expected. Single stepping until exit from `sysrq_dbg_op()` which has no line number information. "Warning: invalid remote reply".
3. GDB 'run' is also not working. It display a message "The remote target does not support run"
4. How can I call a module on my target on which I have put breakpoint as I can not use minicom and gdb concurrently.
5. What all steps I should follow after I freeze the kernel.

What is wrong in this process?

Comment: problem 2 got resolved by changing the gdb version.